# CUDA data initialization

Tags: cuda

As far as the tutorial regarding on CUDA, most of the data is sent to Device by kernel invocation. I wonder if there is anyway I can perform 
Init Data -- Process(s) -- clean up sort of operation in cuda. here is my code I tried but it seems not working.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(value, a) {                            \
    cudaError_t _m_cudaStatus = value;                          \
    if(_m_cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {                          \
        printf("Error &s at line %d in file %s\n",              \
                cudaGetErrorString(_m_cudaStatus),              \
                __LINE__, __FILE__);                            \
        exit(1);                                                \
    } else {printf("Done! - %d\n", a);} }

__constant__
float* data;

__host__ __device__
void initMemory(int size){
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMalloc(&data, sizeof(float) * size), 0);
    float *ha = new float[size];
    for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
        ha[i] = i * 1.0f;
    }
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(data, ha, sizeof(float) * size, 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice), 1);
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), 2);
}

__host__ __device__
void freeMemory(){
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), 3);
    cudaFree(data);
}

__global__
void print(int size){
    printf("size = %d\n", size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("data[%d] = %f\n", i, data[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int size = 1024;

    initMemory(size);
    printf("1\n");
    print<<<1, 1>>>(size);
    printf("2\n");
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    freeMemory();
    printf("3\n");
}
```

In this code I am trying to keep some data initialized by host for one time, and prepare kernel process for many time's invocation and finally free cuda memory by cleanup method. But I am not quite sure if this is the correct way using CUDA and how to modify my code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is completely broken on just  about every level.

Comment: Data is sent to GPUs via `cudaMemcpy`, so your initial assumption is wrong, which makes the entire code "useless"

Comment: @AnderBiguri but I have seen malloc invocation in kernel code which did actually allocate memory at device side. is this not appliable in __device__ function?

Comment: @AnderBiguri and I have tried to use cudaMemCpyToSimple and the code still not working

Comment: You seem to be quite confused with quite a lot of things, by looking at your code. I suggest simplifying your code. Start with smaller steps, as I wouldn't even know where to start answering this question. Try using `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without belaboring the point too much, it is fair to say that you got just about everything wrong in both versions of the code you have shown in your question. It is, therefore, simpler to show what a working version would look like than to explain everything that was incorrect in your two attempts:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(value, a) {                            \
    cudaError_t _m_cudaStatus = value;                          \
    if(_m_cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {                          \
        printf("Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",              \
                cudaGetErrorString(_m_cudaStatus),              \
                __LINE__, __FILE__);                            \
        exit(1);                                                \
    } else {printf("Done! - %d\n", a);} }

__device__ float* data;

void initMemory(int size){
    float* da;
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMalloc(&da, sizeof(float) * size), 0);
    float *ha = new float[size];
    for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
        ha[i] = i * 1.0f;
    }
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMemcpy(da, ha, sizeof(float) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice), 1);
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(data, &da, sizeof(da), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice), 2);
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), 3);
    delete[] ha;
}

void freeMemory(){
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), 4);
    float* da;
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&da, data, sizeof(da), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost), 5);
    CUDA_CHECK_VALUE(cudaFree(da), 6);
}

__global__
void print(int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("data[%d] = %f\n", i, data[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int size = 1024;

    initMemory(size);
    printf("1\n");
    print<<<1, 1>>>(size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("2\n");
    freeMemory();
    printf("3\n");
}
```

A few points:

1. It is important to recognize that `initMemory` and `freeMemory` both run on the host in your code. Decorating your code with `__device__` doesn't  automagically make the code run on the device. It only compiles a version of the code as a device function which can be called within a kernel. At no point do you actually do that, however, so all the code runs on the host, because that is where you called it.
2. `__shared__` and `__constant__` memory can't be dynamically allocated from the host as you have tried to in the two iterations of your code which we have seen
3. Your second implementations of `initMemory` and `freeMemory` require a number of additional CUDA host API functions to be used in order to make things work correctly as should be obvious from the code above.